# Firebase user.sendEmailVerification() to my own address

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Whenever a firebase user creates an account I would like to send the verification mail to my own mail instead of the created user their email.

This is my code:

```js
export function onAuthStateChanged(callback) {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    let userinfo = { uid: "", token: "", name: "", email: "", verified: "" }
    
    if (firebaseUser) {
      userinfo = {
        uid: user.uid,
        token: user.ma,
        name: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        verified: user.emailVerified
      }

      if (!user.emailVerified) {
        user.sendEmailVerification();
      }
    }
  })
}
```

And I tried to edit this line:

```
user.email = "mymail@gmail.com"
user.sendEmailVerification();
```

But 'user' is read-only

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication will only send an email to the account that is specified in the user profile. You can't configure it to send the email elsewhere.

Options I can quickly see:

- Either send an *additional* email to your own a address when you call `user.sendEmailVerification()`.
- Or use your own verification flow entirely, not depending on Firebase Authentication's `user.sendEmailVerification()` method.

Firebase has no specific support for either of these actions, and you'll have to code them yourself as you'd do with any requirement to send email. If you're new to this, you might want to look at [using Cloud Functions to send email](https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+functions+send+email).